# Cannot show data for each post after achieving through jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

This is the fiddle I made first to achieve facebook and twitter shares count

http://jsfiddle.net/v8gw6/1/

and it works well but then I tried it on multiple post it do not respond and this is second fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/v8gw6/3/

This is the code I've used in second fiddle
**HTML**

```
<div class='post'>
    <div class='sharing-bar' data-href='http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/codeanywhere-most-useful-and-multi.html'>
<span class='sum'></span>

<span class='facebook'></span>

<span class='twitter'></span>

    </div>
</div>
<div class='post'>
    <div class='sharing-bar' data-href='http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/which-blog-type-suites-you-best-head-to.html'>
<span class='sum'></span>

<span class='facebook'></span>

<span class='twitter'></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $('.post').each(function () {
        var url = $(this).find('.sharing-bar').attr('data-href');
        var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=" + url;
        $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
            if (data["shares"] != undefined) {
                var fbshares = data["shares"];
            } else {
                var fbshares = 0;
            }
            $(this).find(".sharing-bar .facebook").append(fbshares);
            var url = $(this).find('.sharing-bar').attr('data-href');
            var twitterurl = 'http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?';
            $.getJSON(twitterurl, function (data) {

                var twittershares = data["count"];
                $(this).find(".sharing-bar .twitter").append(twittershares);
                var sumofboth = fbshares + twittershares;
                $(this).find(".sharing-bar .sum").append(sumofboth);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Please help

Comment: your ajax call is failing in 2nd fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your `this` reference because your this reference change in `getJson`method it not pointing to your `post div` so it won't find `.facebook` span

SEE BELOW

```
$('.post').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).find('.sharing-bar').attr('data-href');
    var fburl = "http://graph.facebook.com/?id=" + url;
    // here this is .post object
    var $this= $(this);
    $.getJSON(fburl, function (data) {
        var fbshares = 0;
        if (data["shares"] != undefined) {
            fbshares = data["shares"];
        }
        // here this is not .post object, so store .post object in variable $this and use it.
        this.find(".sharing-bar .facebook").text(fbshares); // it will not work.
        $this.find(".sharing-bar .facebook").text(fbshares); // it will work
    });

    // rest of your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your concept injected a mass knowledge in me. Thanks mate.